# Error not found - path for images

Tags: html, spring, angular, image

I'm using Spring and Angular2 for my app. But my images don't show up in html and I get this error

> GET http://localhost:8080/src/main/resources/images/opcije.png 404 (Not Found)

My root direcoty is kongres-spring, src is inside of it, and other folders structer is the same as in path, and image exist in folder. So, why my picture doesn't show up?

Comment: Could you please provide some code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a standard spring boot project and add your images:

```
src/
src/main
src/main/java
src/main/java/hello
src/main/java/hello/HelloController.java
src/main/java/hello/Application.java
src/main/resources
src/main/resources/static
src/main/resources/static/images
src/main/resources/static/images/test.jpeg
src/test
src/test/java
src/test/java/hello
src/test/java/hello/HelloControllerTest.java
src/test/java/hello/HelloControllerIT.java
```

They will be available at

```
http://localhost:8080/images/test.jpeg
```

See the doc [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot)